# Add .DotSettings file to ReSharper InspectCode

Tags: continuous-integration, resharper, static-code-analysis

I am using the Command Line Tools InspectCode.exe from ReSharper, but I cannot get the same output as when I run ReSharper through Visual Studio.

I currently have ReSharper Ultimate version 10.0.1 on Visual Studio 2013, and have manually edited my Inspection Severity settings to ignore certain issues that are non-issues for my team or stylistic preferences that do not affect my solution during compilation or runtime. This is saved under `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings`

My current InspectCode command looks something like this:

```
InspectCode C:\*solution_location* /o=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\xmlOutput.xml
```

On the JetBrains InspectCode page located [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode), there is mention that InspectCode will find saved configuration files that were created by manually changing ReSharper through Visual Studio, but running both InspectCode and the "ReSharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution" option within Visual Studio  on the same solution file give different results.

The question is, how can I use the configuration file mentioned above in the ReSharper InspectCode command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to copy your `GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings` to `{SolutionName}.sln.dotSettings`, sitting next to your solution file.

Also, make sure that ReSharper and the command line tools are at the same version.

Finally, what's the difference you're seeing? If it's due to an extension, then unfortunately, that's an issue that's not going to be easily solved - the command line tools [don't currently support extensions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-436208).

Comment: The difference is just amount of issues, in the order of a few thousand (mostly stylistic). The other interesting thing is I don't see a `{SolutionName}.sln.dotSettings` present at all next to the solution file, and I have the show hidden files and folders, etc. option enabled, any idea why I can't see that? Also my command line tools version is 10.0.20151218.134438, if that helps any. It looks to be the same for these tools and ReSharper.

Comment: The file should be named after your solution, so `AwesomeApp.sln` would have `AwesomApp.sln.dotSettings`. And it's only created if you explicitly save something to the "Team Shared Settings" layer in the options dialog, so might not exist. You can copy a file and rename it, ReSharper will pick it up.